# Are Noahide women permitted to undergo a tubal ligation?

Tags: gentiles, women, medicine, pregnancy-birth, noachide-laws

Shalom!
I am a non Jewish G-d fearing woman with two children and even though I am still quite young (24) I don't want to have any more children. I have severe depression and anxiety so the two I already have are a big challenge for me! In both my pregnancies my anxiety was even worse so I couldn't imagine to go through this process again (willingly) and I am very much against abortion. But the problem is that due to family history of thrombosis, I am not advised to take birth control in form of hormones. I would therefore like to have my tubes tied to be on the safe side...

**I heard that tubal ligation is prohibited for Jews, but what about Noahides? Does this prohibition also apply for us?**

Comment: Miriam, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please note that we [do not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized advice, so we can address the question with respect to Noahide women in general, but not with respect to your particular situation. Regarding your particular situation, I recommend consulting your rabbi, possibly informed with information you find here.

Answer (score 5):

According to sefer [Sheva Mitzvot Hashem](https://www.noahideshop.com/hebrew-books/37--.html), (Vol II, helek 5, 9:1), a tubal ligation ***is permitted*** for bnot noach. And further says: that even more than this could be done for reasons of safety or health issues.